# Google translate has stopped working in Chrome

Tags: google-translate

Google translate has stopped working in Chrome but still working in Firefox. The code is below and it was working for long time before now:

```
<script>
    function googleSectionalElementInit() {
    new google.translate.SectionalElement({
        sectionalNodeClassName: 'can-translate',
        controlNodeClassName: 'translation-control',
        background: '#ffffcc'
    }, 'google_sectional_element');
    }
    var url = top.location.href,
        pos = url.search(/\/\w\w(\W|$)/),
        lang = url.substring(pos+1,pos+3),
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = false;
        ga.src = 'https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl='+lang;
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
    })();
</script>
```

At the moment here is error:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?client=te&alpha=true&hl=en&cb=_callbacks____0jtqeel7c with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

If it go to the proposed link, here is suggestion:

> Make sure these resources are served with a correct "Content-Type" response header from the list below, as well as a "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" response header.

Also there is message at https://translate.google.com/intl/en/about/website/

> We no longer provide new access to Google Translate's Website Translator. This change does not affect existing use of the Website Translator.

This has affect in Chrome only, code above is Google only <strike>and I've no idea where and how to add `"X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"`</strike>.

UPD: there are both of two necessary headers.

Does Google blocked itself and does anyone know how to fix it?

UPD1: Google translate error began to appear and in Firefox 66.0.1 too. It is

> The resource from “https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?client=te&alpha=true&hl=en&cb=_callbacks____0jttrta1j” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

It looks like some glitch of translation service, after one page refresh it works, after another - server returns incorrect data, json instead of javascript or something like this

Comment: we're seeing the same issue. any luck?

Comment: Now it has now recovered without any actions from my side, Chrome version left the same

Comment: still seeing the issue, surely something changed? What version of chrome are you on?

Comment: Got the same problem here on some machines, but not on others.

Comment: had it on version 72.X, so tried upgrading to 73.0.3683.86, but still seeing the CORB message. Seems to block the actual usage of translate

Comment: Chrome is latest up to date version 73.0.3683.86. Now it seems error message went away

Comment: any solution for this problem? on my sites it still disappear in latest chrome version 73.0.3683.86

Comment: as Oleg said below,if (for me, any) NID cookie is present via a google domain, then the CORBS warning appears when using Google Translate Website Translator via code from Google involving the method: googleTranslateElementInit().Google no longer gives new access to this code, but current users may still use it, ref: https://translate.google.com/intl/en/about/website. If I go into chrome settings 
 and delete the NID cookie, reload the page, the CORBS warning goes away. The NID cookie returns after a couple of reloads due to the cookie coming back. On the latest v.73.0.3683.86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a bug via https://crbug.com/new and try to provide as many details as possible:

- Did the issue work in Chrome 72 and stopped working in Chrome 73?
- Is there a repro page that shows the problem?  What is the expected VS observed behavior?
- Does the issue repro without any Chrome extensions present?
- Does the broken page use AppCache?

Comment: I don't know on which of Chrome versions this began and it seem this is not browsers' bug rather Google service failures

Comment: I've submitted a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=947466

Answer (score 6):

At this point, if you manually delete a cookie with the name "NID" for the host .translate.googleapis.com, you can process the page(CORB error disappears)

By the way, repeated page calls also sometimes remove this error. But the solution to the problem is as strange as its occurrence.

Comment: I don't think one can delete a cookie from another site. My site is showing 2 NID cookies, one from translate.googleapis.com and one from google.com. however, opening site in incognito window doesn't give CORB warning and does not show any NID cookies...

Comment: You can't do it from the script, for a sure. It also has a htmlOnly flag, so you can't even read it(any operations only as a browser owner in Application tab).

Comment: I've setup a codepen to show this. Seems to give CORB message even in Incognito, after using the language tool dropdown and reloading the page. keep at it and you'll get the message. https://s.codepen.io/paul/debug/ZZzEpQ/mWAoNxPzExxr

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue on multiple sites, it first started on Chrome on my Pixel 2.

The widget does appear on the first load sometimes, if not a reload is all that's required, not even a hard reload. My guess would be that Google are trying to phase the widget out.

The widget does still work without any issues on all other browsers.